# How to create a javascript function that will remember the user input and then display summary

Tags: javascript

I have created a form that displays user input after sumbmitting the form on a page. I need to add a fucntion that will remember a previous inputs and display on the same page.
I used document.write to output the form results and it works but I am unable to figure out how to display the summary of all inputs. For example: yu entered order details and then click on "sumbit". It displays the input values. Then you go back and enter new data and click on submit it displays the new data. Say after filling in the form 5 times with different values i need a function that will display the total value of all 5 orders entered, for example the total value of transactions...Perhaps an array that remembers previous inputs?

My HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
     <meta charset=UTF-8">

<!--script area-->

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/CSS" href="formstyle.css">
<script src="millends.js"></script>


<title>
Mill-Ends Order</title>
</head>

<body>
<!--start form-->
<form method="post">

<fieldset>

<h1 class="data_entry">Tickets Order</h1>



<ul>



<li>

<label for="first_name">Customer Name:</label>
<input type="text" id="customer_name" name="customer_name" placeholder="first name and family name" class="medium"/></br>
</li>

<li>
<label for="phone">Phone:</label>
<input type="tel" id="phone" name="phone" required class="telephone"></br></br>

<li>
<label for="number_of_tickets">Number of tickets:</label>
<input type="number" id="number_of_tickets" name="number_of_tickets" required class="small"/>
</li>


<h3 class"address">Delivery Address</h3>
<li>
<label for="street_name">Street:</label>
<input type="text" id="street_name" name="street_name" required placeholder="e.g. 111 Smith St" class="large"/>
</li>

<li><label for="city">City:</label>
<input type="text" id="city" name="city" class="medium"/>
</li>

<li><label for="state">State:(e.g.VIC)</label>
<input type="text" id="state" name="state" required placeholder="XXX" maxlength="3" size="3" class="three" />
</li>

<li>
<label for="post_code">Postcode:</label>
<input type="text" id="post_code" name="post_code" required placeholder="XXXX" maxlength="4" class="four"/>
</li>



<li>
<label for="distance">Distance from Depot(in kms)</label>
<input type="number" id="distance" name="distance" required class="howfar"/><br><br>
</li>


<button class="reset" type="reset" id="clear">Clear Form</button><br><br>


<button onclick="go()">Create Order</button><br><br>

<button onclick="summary()">Daily Sales Summary</button>


</form>


</body>

</script>
</html>
```

My Javascript:

```
function go()

        {




//form fields start here:


        var customer_name = document.getElementById('customer_name').value;
    var phone=document.getElementById('phone').value;
        var street_name=document.getElementById('street_name').value;
    var city=document.getElementById('city').value;
    var state=document.getElementById('state').value;
    var post_code=document.getElementById('post_code').value;
        var distance=document.getElementById('distance').value;
    var number_of_tickets=document.getElementById('number_of_tickets').value;
    var cost_per_ticket=15.20;
    var total_cost_without_gst=cost_per_ticket*number_of_tickets;
    var total_cost_with_gst=(total_cost_without_gst*0.10)+total_cost_without_gst;
    var close_delivery=20;
    var far_delivery=35;
        var close_total=close_delivery+total_cost_with_gst;
        var far_total=far_delivery+total_cost_with_gst;


    var currentDate = new Date()
    var day = currentDate.getDate()
    var month = currentDate.getMonth() + 1
    var year = currentDate.getFullYear()
    var currentTime = new Date()
    var hours = currentTime.getHours()
    var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes()

    if (minutes < 10)
    minutes = "0" + minutes


          if (customer_name=="")
{
alert("Error: please enter customer name")
return false;
}


          if (isNaN(phone))
{
alert("Error: phone must be in numbers");
return false;
}


          if (phone=="")
{
alert("error: please enter customer phone number");
return false;
}    

          if (number_of_tickets=="")
{
alert("error: please enter Number of Tickets");

return false;
}  


          if (isNaN(number_of_tickets))
{
alert("ERROR: tickets must be a number");

return false;
}  

          if (number_of_tickets <= 0)
{
alert("ERROR: number of tickets must be greater than 0");
return false;
}
          if (!(number_of_tickets==Math.round(number_of_tickets)))
{
alert("ERROR: number of tickets must be a whole number");
return false;
}

          if (street_name=="")
{
alert("ERROR: Please enter street name");
return false;
}


          if (city=="")
{
alert("ERROR: Please enter city name");
return false;
}

          if (state=="")
{
alert("ERROR: Please enter state");
return false;
}

          if (isNaN(post_code))
{

        alert("ERROR: Postcode must be a number");

        return false;

}


          if (post_code=="")
{
alert("ERROR: Please enter valid postcode");
return false;
}

          if (isNaN(distance))
{
alert("ERROR: Distance must be a number");
return false;
}


          if (distance=="")
{
alert("ERROR: Please enter distance");
return false;
}

        document.write("Order Date/Time: ","<b>" + day + "/" + month + "/" + year + "<b>" +", ");
        document.write("<b>" + hours + ":" + minutes + " " + "</b>", "<br><br>");

        document.write("ORDER DETAILS",'<br><br><br>',"Customer Name: "+ customer_name,'<br>'); 
        document.write("Phone: "+phone,'<br><br>');

    document.write("--------Delivery Address--------", '<br>'+street_name,'<br>');
    document.write(city,'<br>');
    document.write(state);



        document.write(" "+ post_code, '<br><br>');


    document.write("<u>Order Summary</u>", '<br><br>');

    document.write("Tickets Ordered: " + number_of_tickets, '<br><br>');
    document.write("Cost per ticket: "+"$"+cost_per_ticket.toFixed(2) + '<br><br>');

    document.write("Total cost without GST: " +"$"+total_cost_without_gst.toFixed(2) +'<br><br>');
    document.write("Total cost with GST: "+"$"+total_cost_with_gst.toFixed(2) +'<br><br>');
if(distance>20)
    document.write("Delivery Cost: " +"$"+ far_delivery.toFixed(2)+'<br><br>');
else
    document.write("Delivery Cost: "+"$"+close_delivery.toFixed(2));
    document.write('<br><br>');

if(distance>20)
    document.write("TOTAL ORDER COST: " +"$"+far_total.toFixed(2));
    else
    document.write("TOTAL ORDER COST: "+ "$"+close_total.toFixed(2));



        }
```

Comment: what's the question? please read the FAQ's about how to put together a proper question as well as the do's and don'ts

Comment: What part of your code seems you cannot solve. If you are the one who wrote this code then you know the parts where it freaks out!

Comment: Sorry, I am new to this site, so go easy on me :) I just need a function that will store user input value somewhere (perhaps an array) and upon request will display the summary of all inputs so far.

Comment: I need to add a function, not to fix the code. Function that will remember the user inputs so I can display a daily summary. I have created a daily sales summary button but it is not scripted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple task, basically we need a `button` that when we click it outputs form elements inside some output element, I will use a `div`. To get elements in JavaScript we can assign `id`'s to elements and do this: `document.getElementById("elementIdName")` to retrieve those values. From there we can use `onclick` which will activate when we click an element, `value` is to retrieve input values, and `innerHTML` to assign HTML to some element. Here is a simple example of getting a single input element, we called `name`. And outputting: `Your name is 'nameHere'`:

For storing all out input we use an `array`, each time we submit our data we want to `push()` our current values input our global array. I will call this `allNames` for the example.

**HTML**

```
<label>Enter Name:</label><input type="text" id="name" />
<button id="submit">Submit</button>
<button id="showAll">Show All</button>
<div id="output"></div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var allNames = [];

document.getElementById("submit").onclick = function()
{
    var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "Your name is "+name;
    allNames.push(name);    
}

document.getElementById("showAll").onclick = function()
{
    var names = "Names: ";
    for(name in allNames) names += allNames[name] + ", ";
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = names;
}
```

Here is an example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ghbAQ/1/

Comment: Hi Spencer, thanks very much for your reply. I used document.write to output the form results and it works but I am unable to figure out how to display the summary of all inputs. For example: yu entered order details and then click on "sumbit". It displays the input values. Then you go back and enter new data and click on submit it displays the new data. Say after filling in the form 5 times with different values i need a function that will display the total value of all 5 orders entered, for example the total value of transactions...Perhaps an array that remembrs previous inputs?

Comment: Yes we can do that, give me a few minutes to edit my answer. We can start with an empty array and call `push()` for each submit.

Comment: thanks very much again man, expecially for not voting my question down like others :)

Comment: Alright I've updated my answer. No problem, many people tend to be a bit harsh on newcomers. But don't blame them, the rules are strict for good reasons.

Comment: Thanks Spencer, you are a champ! I can't vote you up because my reputation currently sucks (and this is only after 1 question). Much appreciate it, have a great day!

Comment: yes, I understand the reasons, no hard feelings for others either :)

Comment: Hi Spencer, I was wondering if you could help me a little bit further: by using the push method, how do I display the sum rather than the outputs next to each other. I.e if I want to display the total nember of tickets as 40, instead of total number of tickets 20, 20. Does it make sense? Thanks in advance

Comment: If we only cared about the total number of tickets then we don't even need an array, just some variable that holds the sum some global variable like: `var sum = 0;`. And for each submit you can do: `sum += tickets;`. If you wish to know the sum and the number of tickets for each submit, then you would use an array and use a `for` loop to add all the values to a single local sum variable.

Comment: amm...do you mind providing an example? tried using an array like in your first example it worked but sum global variable it doesn't...

Comment: Here: http://jsfiddle.net/ghbAQ/12/ , we don't need an array. Just a single variable.